# Stop Python localhost server on every port

Tags: python, server, localhost

Since I tried a tutorial with Python / Django using `venv` etc, i'm blocked with a localhost server that shows folder of this project:

[image]

I use Visual Studio Code and I use LiveServer configured on port 0. Each time I want to start LiveServer, it renders me this page and nothing else.

Have you any idea why and how to stop it?

I modified my PATH folder to make the Python's project work. Is it the problem?

Thank you

Comment: 0 to 1023 is typically reserved why not use something else?

Comment: Also like venky__ said try to use something higher than 3000.

Comment: In LiveServer doc it is said that setting this line  "liveServer.settings.port": 0 will generate a random port num. Cf. screenshot: it's running on port 55012. When I stop LiveServer and running it again, this is the same page that appears...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to fix this is by going to VS Code >> File >> Open Folder, and the select the folder with your html file in it then you can run live server properly. However, if you want to stop live server simply closing the web browser it's running on will do.

Comment: Ok I wouldn't have thought I would be so easy. I was still on the Python folder with only a html page opened, that was causing the problem. Ty!

Comment: @Veermo no problem